# Glassfish file open error in /AppData/Local/Temp/osgiapp...?

Tags: web-applications, deployment, osgi, glassfish-3

I'm deploying my war as an OSGi bundle but kept getting this error:

```
[#|2016-09-12T13:39:59.409+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8004: file open failure; file = file:/C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/osgiapp2866222350344881589/WEB-INF/lib/Bundle295.jar|#]
```

I have no idea why glassfish was looking for that `Bundle295.jar` file. It's NOT in my war's `WEB-INF/lib`.

Also, I noticed, if I remove the classpaths to `el-api` and `el-impl`, the problem goes away, but of course I'll have some other class def not found error due to missing library.

In other words, the problem seems to occur only when I added classpaths the two jars `WEB-INF/lib/el-api-2.2.jar` and `WEB-INF/lib/el-impl-2.2.jar` in my `MANIFEST.MF` file like this:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes,
 WEB-INF/lib/el-api-2.2.jar,
 WEB-INF/lib/el-impl-2.2.jar,
 WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar,
 WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.2.1.jar,
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

GlassFish creates temporary files in the location specified in `-Djava.io.tmpdir` at various points during the lifecycle of apps. This looks like a temporary directory created by Felix (the OSGi container) for the purposes of caching. These temporary files are cleared away when the server is gracefully shutdown, but can hang around if the server is killed or an error occurs which terminates the JVM.

You should be able to delete the `..\osgiapp...` folder without any side effects and restart GlassFish to avoid the problem.

The server log message seems to be just a `WARNING` - is it actually causing any problem? If not, it can be ignored.

Comment: Hey @Mike. Although it's a warning, when the error show, the page just doesn't load.
Also, none of the classes in my library jars are found.